# VERY simple C# Set implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, set

This is not meant to solve any insane real world problems. I just want to make sure my Set logic is right and the code looks okay. It feels weird implementing it with a `Dictionary` of dummy values but it seems that's how most languages do it anyway. What do you think?

```
public class Set : IEnumerable
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<object, bool> _items;

        public Set()
        {
            _items = new Dictionary<object, bool>();
        }

        public void Add(object item)
        {
            if (!_items.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                _items.Add(item, true);
            }
        }

        public void Remove(object item)
        {
            if (_items.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                _items.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        public bool Contains(object item)
        {
            return _items.ContainsKey(item);
        }

        public int Count()
        {
            return _items.Keys.Count;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _items.Clear();
        }

        public void UnionWith(Set input)
        {
            foreach (var item in input.Cast<object>().Where(item => !_items.ContainsKey(item)))
            {
                _items.Add(item, true);
            }
        }

        public void IntersectWith(Set input)
        {
            var newSet = new Set();
            foreach (var item in _items.Keys.Where(input.Contains))
            {
                newSet.Add(item);
            }
            Clear();
            foreach (var item in newSet)
            {
                _items.Add(item, true);
            }
        }

        public void DifferenceWith(Set input)
        {
            var newSet = new Set();
            foreach (var item in _items.Keys.Where(item => !input.Contains(item)))
            {
                newSet.Add(item);
            }
            Clear();
            foreach (var item in newSet)
            {
                _items.Add(item, true);
            }
        }

        public bool IsSubsetOf(Set input)
        {
            return _items.Keys.All(input.Contains);
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _items.Keys.GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are aware that System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T> contains exactly the same methods you have defined, except `DifferenceWith()` is called `ExceptWith()`?

Comment: Yup! This was just to see if I could re-implement more or less the same thing as practice.

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to reinvent the wheel but it seems like cheating to create a HashSet based on a more advanced feature like Dictionary.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,2d265edc718b158b,references

Comment: Heh, fair enough @RickDavin, I totally agree :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you already know about [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ISet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081(v=vs.110).aspx) in the following review and are just missing the reinventing-the-wheel tag.

**ICollection**

You've got Add, Remove, Clear, Count, and Contains. If you add a `CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)` and `bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }` to your implementation then you can implement ICollection.

**Why Dictionary?**

Perhaps you'd be better suited with a `HashSet<T>` implementation? Correct me if I'm wrong but it doesn't appear you're actually using the boolean value of the dictionary, so you'd be better suited with a `Hashset<T>`.

**Generics**

You could create a generic implementation `Set<T>` fairly easily. And if you wanted to still allow your existing functionality then you'd use `Set<object>`.

**Set Operations**

Perhaps consider having your operator functions return the new set from their actions?

For example,

```
public Set UnionWith(Set input)
{
    var unionedSet = new Set(_items); // See suggestion below.
    foreach (var item in input.Where(x => _items.ContainsKey(item)))
    {
        unionedSet.Add(item, true);
    }

    return unionedSet;
}
```

**Constructor**

Adding the ability to give `IEnumerable` or `ICollection` of items in a constructor could be really helpful, especially if you have your set operations return new sets as suggested above.

Comment: Just trying to re-invent the wheel as practice, so you are correct :) Good notes about the Dictionary. I guess writing this, I was almost trying to pretend HashSet was not an option (or else I could just use that in the first place), so I went with a Dictionary that used dummy values.

I guess you're right about the generic version. Set's (at least in mathematics), are not strictly the same type, they can be anything, so that's what I was going for there.

I thought the same about the operations, I think I'll fool around with that. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott I figured that was the case which is why I mentioned the `Set<object>` usage. Reduces the casting and increases performance as a result which is usually important for data-structures.

Comment: @Scott As for reinventing the wheel, it might be a decent idea to just create a set data-structure that implements the `ISet<T>` interface. Then look into ways the `ISet<T>` interface is used and test or make use of it that way.